# Retorno falso ao comparar duas strings identicas em python

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, string, comparação

Estou tentando comparar duas strings, uma vem do banco de dados como um array, a outra é escrita a mão:

```py
  string = str(profile[1]) #Carlos Gimenes
  print(string == str('Carlos Gimenes'))
  #Retorna false
```

Já tentei de várias formas e não consigo fazer isso retornar true, ao exibir o tipo da variável é retornado que ambas são `<class 'str'>`, ainda sim o valor retornado continua como false.

link do projeto:https://github.com/CaduGimenes/recognizer

Comment: desnecessario converter  usando str, redundante. faço um debug simples para garantir mesmo que ao iguais: string = str(profile[1]); string2 = 'Carlos Gimenes'; print(string, string2, sep='\n')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifiquei o binário do banco de dados do projeto e conforme a imagem abaixo pode ser que exista um erro de digitação na hora de ter adicionado os dados de teste e por conta disso o resultado da expressão `string == str('Carlos Gimenes'` é falso.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem verificamos a existência de 'Carlos GimenesV' com o **V** no final da string.

Conforme o @EltonNunes falou basta comparar os valores das strings no console e verificar se os valores são de fato iguais.

Esse tipo de problema acontece de forma que não percebemos e é **recomendadíssimo** realizar essas verificações iniciais para descobrir o problema, no caso verificar **o valor de fato da variável**.

```
print(string, string2, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado, por algum motivo o dado estava sendo inserido com espaço antes e depois.